# How do I (can I at all?) write a reference to a file in a directory outside of the current wiki directory for wiki mode for emacs?

Tags: emacs, wiki

I'm using wiki-mode for emacs, and I'm trying to figure out how to short-hand reference files that are in directories external to the current directory. I figured the syntax would look something like [[..\..\directory\fileName][short name]] but that doesn't seem to work (or maybe I have some small syntax details wrong?).

Is this something that's doable with wikimode for emacs? If so, how?